# Play audio from the commandline through javafx

Tags: java, command-line, javafx, raspberry-pi, playback

I am running javafx 8 from my raspberry pi and since the media library is not supported on this platform, is there a way i can play audio but by executing aplay from the commandline like below. the code below is not working.

```
p = new ProcessBuilder( "aplay", "police_s.wav").start();
```

Comment: I also tried "Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"aplay ~/javafx/examples/PrayerTime/dist/police_s.wav"});"